# SQL Comparing nchar to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns:

- id (nchar)
- name (varchar)

Something simple just can't figure out how.

```
    select *
    from plant.carrier
    where carrier_id like 'NT'
```

This gives an expression error

```
      SELECT *
      FROM plant.carrier
      WHERE RTrim(CAST([carrier_id] As VarChar) = 'NT'
```

id column

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [plant].[carrier](
    [carrier_id] [nchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_carrier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [carrier_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS =enter code here ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Did you try [Cast or Convert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I tried cast(id AS text) didnt work, the systax is correct but still returns nothing despite having data there as nchar.

Comment: I have a nchar NT and I cannot get that out when i use

Comment: You know what datatype you need to compare it to, so why would you use `Text` instead?

Comment: better check u r collation as it is nchar , collate it with normal and try

Comment: Can you show us the schema, sample code and the exact error message you are getting. That will go a long way towards helping us help you.

Comment: I am not getting a error message when i use

  select *
  from plant.carrier
  where carrier_id like 'NT'

But i am getting no rows returned yet their is NT in the id nchar column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare nchar and varchar you need to convert char to varchar and compare two varchars:

```
RTrim(CAST([nCharColumn] As VarChar)
```

**Updated**

Here is full example:

```
create table test (
f nchar(20))

insert into test values('nt')
insert into test values('st')

declare @s varchar(20) = 'nt'
select * from test where rtrim(cast(f as varchar)) = @s
```

**Updated 2**

```
CREATE TABLE [carrier](
    [carrier_id] [nchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_carrier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [carrier_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into carrier values('nt', 'nt')
insert into carrier values('st', 'st')

declare @s varchar(20) = 'nt'
select * from carrier where rtrim(cast([carrier_id] as varchar)) = @s
```

This works fine for me too. It returns one record.

Answer (score 3):

If you [**Read The Documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx), you'll see that conversion between `[var]char` and `n[var]char` is implicit, so saying something like

```
where x.some_char_column = y.some_nchar_column
```

should work just fine...unless the columns differ in their defined collation. Then you might have a problem.

[image: T-SQL data type conversion table]

Comment: might as well throw this in there, because OP isn't likely to read it now if they haven't already: `Implicit conversions are not visible to the user. SQL Server automatically converts the data from one data type to another. For example, when a smallint is compared to an int, the smallint is implicitly converted to int before the comparison proceeds.`

Comment: Please note that doing comparisons in WHERE or JOIN clauses between strings of different types (one column an nvarchar, the other a varchar) introduces some really bad performance problems in SQL Server.  I mean, really significant performance problems.  Whenever possible, such string type mismatches should be eliminated.

Comment: @pmbAustin: That will be true regardless of whether the conversion is explicit or implicit. And if you're comparing to a string literal or constant expression (as is the case in the O.P.'s problem statement), the optimizer is probably &mdash; or, at least, it should be &mdash; smart enough to do the conversion up front and avoid conversion issues. It is entirely possible, though, that it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use rtrim when comparing string values. sql server will ignore spaces on the right side of any string for an equality check regardless if the datatype is (n)char or (n)varchar.

Either of these slight modifications to your original should work just fine. They both work with your posted table.

```
select *
from carrier
where carrier_id like 'NT%'

SELECT *
FROM carrier
WHERE [carrier_id] = 'NT'
```

Comment: The spaces were on the left for whatever reason so i used a ltrim.

Comment: Oh...well hopefully your table isn't too big as this nonSARGable and any index you have on that column will be unusable.